# Failed to build app with Apache Cordova on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a problem with Apache Cordova to build my application . I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit able to investigate the matter fy he found that there are similar issues in this release of Ubuntu , version *Cordova* I use is the **6.3.0** Tools required to build such applications child these and Con their respective version: version of *nodejs* **4.2.6**, version of *apache ant* **1.9.6**, *java-8-openjdk-i386*, *SDK manager* rev **25.1.7** tools *Android SDK tools* version **25.1.7**, *Android SDK platform-tools* versión **24.0.1**, *Android SDK build-tools* version **24.0.1**, *Android 6.0* **(API 23)**, Extras *Google repository* y *Android support repository*.

Environment variables "SDK" location -> ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/sdk/tools
```

when you run the command

```
:~/cordovaApp$ cordova build android
```

as a result receive error

```
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.157 secs
Error: /home/ricar1997/cordovaApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Someone who has the same problem in ubuntu 16.04 would be helpful if you could find the solution to this issue.

Comment: Can you run the build with the following: cordova build android --stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem is that I am using the Android sdk build-tools 24.0.1 sdk and this version brings the judgment, those who have the same problem I should install an earlier version to this, for example, 23.0.3 work properly! I hope that it will help for those who
have the same system with the same problem, Greetings!

[look here Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN0g5.png)

The selected version work properly !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ricardo Moreno I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.
I downloaded 23.0.3 build-tools & renamed build-tools folder for 24.0.1. Then the build was generated with no errors.

`/home/mE/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3
/home/mE/Android/Sdk/build-tools/renamed-24.0.1`